# Get user name and email using Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am using this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client
to authenticate a user, auth is working fine, problem is, I was thinking to use the token that I get after login to get the user name and email (as I need not only access to the inbox, contacts, and calendar; but also link the user to a rol using an email).
The problem is, when I get the token, **I get a long string as userId (I guess encrypted). Is there any way I can use this package to get the email?**

This is the section where I get the token back

```
public SessionTokenCache(string userId, HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        cacheId = userId + "_TokenCache";
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        Load();
    }
```

This is the tutorial I followed
https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a token, maybe you can use the Graph API to get details for the logged on user? The result is Json which can be used to extract the bits you want.

```
        public static async Task<string> GetUserData(string token)
    {
        //get data from API
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
        message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return responseString;
        else
            return null;
    }
```